# Can I shrink Div and all nested Divs with simple css rules?

Tags: html, css, mobile, resize, fluid-layout

I mobilizing a website and would like to know if I can use one or more rather simple css rules to shrink a main div that has many nested divs and still have everything look proportonate in the smaller screen. The page is... http://www.junkyardzombiez.com/choose-a-zombie/ and the container is       Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magical way to to do as it's something that needs to be built into the site initially. If you had written the CSS to use `%` rather than `PX` then you would have more scope to work with but hard coded PX values mean it's built to stay at that size.

As it stands at the moment, you will need to change a number of classes to scale in width based on screen size.

It's worth looking at some frameworks like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) that can help with this.

Comment: So might it help if I give the top level div a width of 100% and make all the child divs have a width of 'auto'?

Comment: Not really as this doesn't tell the browser what width a div should be at. Setting them to auto would just mean all divs take on the parent width. Using bootstrap at this point with the classes might be of benefit.